# MonoTouch and Xcode 4

Tags: xamarin.ios

Now that the Xcode 4 GM seed has been released, will MonoDevelop eventually interact with it somehow for XIB editing?  I'm currently manually setting the "Open With..." on each of my XIBs to the old Interface Builder, but there are two problems with this: I have to remember to do it; and any XIB editing enhancements Apple makes in Xcode 4 aren't available.

Comment: Comment from @JLA: Since XCode 4 is now out - any update on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4 GM is under NDA, so nothing can be discussed about it publically.

Comment: You're asking about MonoDevelop/MonoTouch integrating with a NDA'd product.  We cannot comment on that while said product is NDA'd.

Comment: I might point out, though, that Apple has made much about Xcode 4 public - see [link](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html).

Answer (score 3):

Support was previewed here: http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2011/05/preview_xcode_4_support_monotouch

Given the current status of MonoTouch, I think it's safe to assume you will not see this in MonoTouch as it exists now. Presumably this development will be carried over into the new iPhone/Mono product from Xamarin (http://www.xamarin.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Adding outlets and actions is no longer there. XCode 4 now integrates these in code directly, but that is Objective C only, not C#.