# XCode 4 Interface Builder with MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xcode4

It seems impossible to create outlets and actions when running the now integrated Interface Builder in XCode 4, using MonoDevelop 2.4.2 and MonoTouch trial. Doesn´t it work with XCode 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MonoTouch and Xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939302/monotouch-and-xcode-4)

Answer (score 2):

[This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939302/monotouch-and-xcode-4). Also xcode 4 is pre-release software so it is under NDA - none of the Monotouch guys can say anything about the inner-goings on with the program + integration with Monodevelop.